# how to create new instance copying values from other PHP object

Tags: php

For a metering project, I have a class MeterReadings, with a constructor that takes a previous reading as basis for all of its property values except the timestamp. In the example, the Object has only 3 properties, in real life there are many more. I could line by line for each property X do

```
$this->propertyX=$prevMS->propertyX
```

but that quickly becomes tedious.

What is best practice for copying all property values from the `$prevMS` object?

```
<?php class MeterReadings{
    function __construct($prevMS=NULL){
        if($prevMS===NULL){
            $this->gas=0;
            $this->water=0;
            $this->electricity=0;
        }else{
          //PHP can duplicate an object by assignment,
          //so I expected to be able to create a copy of $prevMS 
          //but cannot $this=$prevMS;
          //and cannot $this= clone $that;
          //which both throw error 'Cannot re-assign $this'
          foreach($prevMS as $key => $value){
            //logs "Undefined property: MeterReadings::$0"  
            print "$key => $value\n";   
            $this->$key = $prevMS->$value;
          }
        }
        $this->date=time();//set timestamp for this object
    }
}
$test= new MeterReadings();
$test2 = new MeterReadings($test);
print_r($test);
print_r($test2);
?>gets me

gas => 0
water => 0
electricity => 0
date => 1434448706
MeterReadings Object
 (
    [gas] => 0
    [water] => 0
    [electricity] => 0
    [date] => 1434448706
)
MeterReadings Object
(
    [gas] => 
    [water] => 
    [electricity] => 
    [date] => 1434448706
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clone` and the `__clone` [Magic Method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) to manage what get's cloned.

For example:

```
class Test
{
    public $value1;
    public $value2;
    public $timestamp;

    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->timestamp = null;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->value1 = 1;
$test->value2 = 2;
$test->timestamp = time();

$test2 = clone $test;

print_r($test2);

// Test Object
// (
//     [value1] => 1
//     [value2] => 2
//     [timestamp] => 
// )
```

**Alternative:**

To keep things as in the `__constuct` as specified the comment below:

```
class Test
{
    public $value1;
    public $value2;
    public $timestamp;

    public function __construct (Test $copy = null)
    {
        if($copy) {
            foreach ($copy as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
        $this->timestamp = 'whoop';
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->value1 = 1;
$test->value2 = 2;
$test->timestamp = 'whatev\'s';

$test2 = new Test($test);

print_r($test2);

// Test Object
// (
//     [value1] => 1
//     [value2] => 2
//     [timestamp] => 'whoop'
// )
```

This will work for objects that are **not** itterable and for properties that are protected (but not private). For objects that are itterable and return something else, you can use `get_object_vars()`, [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php). For stuff that's private (are you sure you need private, that's unusual) you'll need to create getters. They can be protected if you don't want them externally available.

Comment: DanielM, thanks for URLing the Magic Method. I'm trying to keep everything within the __construct method, but `$this = clone ($prevMS);` is not allowed. The hope is to keep all values private to the class. I adapt the question to this end.

Comment: Objects in PHP are stored as references. Even if you _could_ do `$this = $object` you'd have to references to the same object. As an alternative you can do `foreach($object as $key => $value) { $this->$key = $value; }`. The object does not need to be itterable for this to work. If the object _is_ itterable, then you can use `get_object_vars()`

Comment: Thanks. We have concurrently edited question and answer. I see my error; shoudln't refer to `$prevMS->$value` but to `$value` only.

Comment: I think you mean "you'd have tWo references". It is working now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yup. I'm really bad for not reading my posts before hitting submit. :p I'm probably in the top 5% of repeat editors for that reason. :p